# Issues with storing and retrieving data from Google Sheets cache

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wrote a function to retrieve Yahoo! Finance data for certain stocks. The sheet was, however, generating too many URL calls to Yahoo! and I was regularly restricted for the rest of the day.

Since the data that I am retrieving is not expected to change often anyway, the solution seems to be using Google Sheets cache to store any values that are retrieved for 7 days before querying live again.

The code is as follows, and a link to the spreadsheet I'm using is below:

```
function yahoofinance(ticker) 
{
    var url = 'https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/' + encodeURI(ticker) + '?modules=price,assetProfile,summaryDetail';
  
    var cache  = CacheService.getDocumentCache();
    var cached = cache.get(url);
  
    if (cached != null) 
    {
        var object = cached; 
        var source = 'cache';
    }
    else
    {
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { muteHttpExceptions: true });
        var responseCode = response.getResponseCode();
  
        if (responseCode === 200)
        {
            var object = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
            var source = 'live';
            
            cache.put(url, "cached", 21600);
            properties.setProperty(url, object);
        }
    }
    
    var fwdPE  = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.summaryDetail?.forwardPE?.fmt || '-';
    var sector = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.assetProfile?.sector          || '-';
    var mktCap = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.price?.marketCap?.fmt         || '-';

    return [[source, fwdPE, sector, mktCap]];
}
```

[Link to the Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rO10X-0VtPfH1D5gPmxe8RFsxWkopLLT7k3_Cby_lfM/edit#gid=0)

The problem is that any function call gets the same error:

```
Error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'result' of undefined (line 28).
```

Line 28 is:

```
var fwdPE  = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.summaryDetail?.forwardPE?.fmt || '-';
```

As far as I understand, `object` (and thus `result[]`) should be available.

- What am I doing wrong. Why is this error generated?
- Am Implementing Google cache correctly? What do I need to improve?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you run your script and `url` is cached, it is a string not an object.  So the next time you try to run your script `object` is string.

Comment: How do I correctly turn te string back into an object? I tried ` var object = eval(cached);` but this does not seem to do anything?

Comment: I really don't understand what you are doing.  I'm assuming your script is run in a loop of symbols so you are still making the same number of URL calls whether you use Cache or not.  The URL fetch quota is 20,000/day. Why not simply store in a spreadsheet?  Also the life of the Cache is indeterminable so no guarantee the cache will contain the data 7 days from now.

Comment: I'm calling this script indeed for about 500 symbols in a spreadsheet. So I'm making 500 calls. But if I reload the spreadsheet, it is making the 500 calls again. Especially now that I'm developing the spreadsheet, I'm refreshing, opening and closing the spreadsheet regularly and then I hit the quotum. I'm just trying to prevent running the script from running more than, say once per 24 hrs or once per week for each symbol.

Comment: If you are developing the spreadsheet reduce the number of calls you make, lets say only 5.  Then when you have fully debugged your script go to full production.  That's what I do.

Comment: I use GOOGLEFINANCE to get stock data for a plotting and trend analysis probram I wrote.  I get chunks of data between dates and add to a historical data sheet for each symbol.  If the data is up to date GOOGLEFINANCE is not used, it is simply ignored and I plot the available data.  You could do the same by simply putting a date stamp on the data and if it is the current data ignore the UrlFetch.  The use of CacheService seems overkill IMHO.

Comment: That seems to be a much better idea actually. I will try to rewrite my script accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

#### Try it this way

```
function yahoofinance(ticker) {
  const url = 'https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/' + encodeURI(ticker) + '?modules=price,assetProfile,summaryDetail';
  const cache = CacheService.getDocumentCache();
  const cached = cache.get("response");
  let object = {};
  if (cached) {
    object.response = cached;
    object.source = 'cache';
  } else {
    let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { muteHttpExceptions: true });
    if (response.getResponseCode() == 200) {
      object.response = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
      object.source = 'live';
      cache.put("response", cached, 21600);
    }
  }
  let fwdPE = object.response.quoteSummary.result[0]?.summaryDetail?.forwardPE?.fmt || '-';
  let sector = object.response.quoteSummary.result[0]?.assetProfile?.sector || '-';
  let mktCap = object.response.quoteSummary.result[0]?.price?.marketCap?.fmt || '-';
  return [[object.source, fwdPE, sector, mktCap]];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have updated the test-sheet (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rO10X-0VtPfH1D5gPmxe8RFsxWkopLLT7k3_Cby_lfM/edit?usp=sharing) but it is never using cache it seems. Every ticker, every time, returns "live" data. Any thoughts?

Comment: I found that "cached" is always null so I assumed that's because the market is closed.